# How can I organize each scraped item into a csv row?

Tags: python, django, csv

What is the best way to organize scraped data into a csv? More specifically each item is in this form

```
url
"firstName middleInitial, lastName - level - word1 word2 word3, &amp; wordN practice officeCity."
JD, schoolName, date
```

Example:

```
http://www.examplefirm.com/jang
"Joe E. Ang - partner - privatization mergers, media &amp; technology practice New York."
JD, University of Chicago Law School, 1985
```

I want to put this item in this form:

```
(http://www.examplefirm.com/jang, Joe, E., Ang, partner, privatization mergers, media &amp; technology, New York, University of Chicago Law School, 1985)
```

so that I can write it into a csv file to import to a django db.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no short cut on this.  Line 1 is easy.  Just assign it to `url`.  Line 3 can probably be split on `,` without any ill effects, but line 2 will have to be manually parsed.  What do you know about word1-wordN?  Are you sure "practice" will never be a "word".  Are you sure the words are only one word long?  Can they be quoted?  Can they contain dashes?

Then I would parse out the beginning and end bits, so you're left with a list of words, split it by commas and/or &amp; (is there a consistent comma before &amp;?  Your format says yes, but your example says no.)  If there are a variable number of words, you don't want to inline them in your tuple like that, because you don't know how to get them out.  Create a list from your words, and add that as one element of the tuple.

```
>>> tup = (url, first, middle, last, rank, words, city, school, year)
>>> tup
('http://www.examplefirm.com/jang', 'Joe', 'E.', 'Ang', 'partner', 
['privatization mergers', 'media &amp; technology'], 'New York', 
'University of Chicago Law School', '1985')
```

More specifically?  You're on your own there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'll eliminate line 2 and use the rest. But, how did you get the actual items into tup?

Comment: Look into the builtin str methods.  `.split()`, `.index()`, `len()`, and the slicing syntax could all be useful.  Just take it one piece at a time.